# Isolate a person from a video, turn to silhouette and back

Tags: animation, materials, image

apologies for the chaotic description, I've been at this for a while and brain no worky properly.

I have a video added via "Images as planes". I would like to animate the girl in the image from person to silhouette / voronoi texture and back.

I managed to isolate the person from the black background and add a texture, but I cannot seem to properly switch between displaying the person and displaying the textured silhouette. What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You need a 1 or 0 value to fully switch the *Mix shader node*. The Distance node outputs some value in between. You can use *Math > Greater Than* node to get 1/0 values.

Comment: Ďakujem! :) This helped, I did try using the _Greather Than_ node but either in the wrong place or I messed up the values, sticking it after _Distance_ and set properly to 0 did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 1 or 0 value to fully switch inputs of the *Mix shader node*.
The *Math > Distance* node outputs some value in between.

You can use *Math > Greater Than node* to get either 1 or 0 values.